# Bug with class names in xcode/swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, subclass

Created the following files (view with xib and view controller):

```
SomeViewController.swift 
SomeView.swift
SomeView.xib
```

**NOTE:** The names may differ but the class names should look similar as in this example.

`SomeViewController` is just a subclass of `UIViewController` and **is not linked with `SomeView` at all**.

But when I use `SomeViewController` it somehow calls `awakeFromNib()` in `SomeView` and it causes crash. Checked twice - the bug won't appear if I for example change class name from `SomeViewController` to `SomeViewController2`.

Code for my case:

```
let vc = SomeViewController()
... //add it to UITabBarController
```

Must I rename it to something fully different or can I somehow fix this link between view and view controller?

Comment: Compare https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621454-loadview: “A view controller has an associated nib file ... if iOS finds a nib file in the app bundle with a name based on the view controller's class name.”

Comment: How does your view controller create its view? Does it have a `view` property`?

Comment: @MartinR look at answer and solution in it

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621487-nibname

> If the view controller class name ends with the word ‘Controller’, as
>   in MyViewController, it looks for a nib file whose name matches the
>   class name without the word ‘Controller’, as in MyView.nib.

Solution:

```
class SomeViewController: UIViewController {
    override var nibName: String? {
        return nil
    }
}
```